Trying to create a donchian breakout system (55day lookback)
'''from backtesting import Backtest, Strategy
from backtesting.test import GOOG
import numpy as np

class DonchianChannelStrategy(Strategy):
    def init(self):
        self.entry_price = None
        self.entry_multiplier = 1.5
        self.stoploss_multiplier = 2.0
        self.trailing_stoploss_multiplier = 3.0
        self.entry_atr_period = 14

    def atr(self, period):
        trs = [max(self.data.High[i] - self.data.Low[i], abs(self.data.High[i] - self.data.Close[i-1]), abs(self.data.Low[i] - self.data.Close[i-1])) for i in range(1, len(self.data))]
        atr = np.mean(trs[-period:])
        return atr

    def next(self):
        donchian_high = max(self.data.High[-55:])
        donchian_low = min(self.data.Low[-55:])
        
        if self.position:
            # Exit condition: trailing stoploss
            stop_loss = self.data.Close - self.atr(self.entry_atr_period) * self.trailing_stoploss_multiplier
            stop_loss = max(stop_loss, stop_loss[-1])  # Ensure stop loss never decreases
            if self.data.Low < stop_loss:
                self.position.close()
        else:
            if self.data.Close > donchian_high:
                self.entry_price = self.data.Close + self.atr(self.entry_atr_period) * self.entry_multiplier
                stop_loss = self.data.Close - self.atr(self.entry_atr_period) * self.stoploss_multiplier
                self.buy(size=self.p.buy_size, exectype=bt.Order.Market, price=self.entry_price, stop=stop_loss)
            elif self.data.Close < donchian_low:
                self.entry_price = self.data.Close - self.atr(self.entry_atr_period) * self.entry_multiplier
                stop_loss = self.data.Close + self.atr(self.entry_atr_period) * self.stoploss_multiplier
                self.sell(size=self.p.sell_size, exectype=bt.Order.Market, price=self.entry_price, stop=stop_loss)

bt = Backtest(GOOG, DonchianChannelStrategy, cash=10000, commission=.002)
stats = bt.run()
print(stats)
bt.plot()'''

'''Start                     2004-08-19 00:00:00
End                       2013-03-01 00:00:00
Duration                   3116 days 00:00:00
Exposure Time [%]                         0.0
Equity Final [$]                      10000.0
Equity Peak [$]                       10000.0
Return [%]                                0.0
Buy & Hold Return [%]              703.458242
Return (Ann.) [%]                         0.0
Volatility (Ann.) [%]                     0.0
Sharpe Ratio                              NaN
Sortino Ratio                             NaN
Calmar Ratio                              NaN
Max. Drawdown [%]                        -0.0
Avg. Drawdown [%]                         NaN
Max. Drawdown Duration                    NaN
Avg. Drawdown Duration                    NaN
# Trades                                    0
Win Rate [%]                              NaN
Best Trade [%]                            NaN
Worst Trade [%]                           NaN
Avg. Trade [%]                            NaN
Max. Trade Duration                       NaN
Avg. Trade Duration                       NaN
Profit Factor                             NaN
Expectancy [%]                            NaN
SQN                                       NaN
_strategy                 DonchianChannelS...
_equity_curve                          Equ...
_trades                   Empty DataFrame'''

What I am trying to create: 55 day period Donchian channel with 14 period ATR with 1.5x multiplier on when the signal is created (when the upper or lower channel is broken) to get a ENTRY level. When the 1.5x multiplier level is breached then it should take an entry when that daily candle has closed by also having a 14 period ATR of 2x multiplier for stoploss
OBS: Im a newbie

So you wrote some code and it doesn't do anything... Try to trace through the code execution to see what is and what is not executed. Also, why is "from backtesting import strategy" commented out? Consider starting from a documented example of 'backtesting' package usage and verify that it works, then go back to your code.
